# (Internal)CA signed certificate on WebLogic & same CA cert(public key) on my Weblogic Server. Browser still doesn't trust

Tags: ssl, weblogic, sslhandshakeexception

I have the company CA signed certificate, intermediate and server certificate in the identity store ( .jks) but still the browser says , cannot be verified by a trusted authority error. Using weblogic -10.3.1 from the weblogic logs i also notice this -

Invalid/unknown SSL header was received from peer x.y.z.12 during  SSL handshake

But when I install the root and intermediate certificates into certmgr.msc then when i access the url again in a new window it has no error on the browser and also no error log in the weblogic server.

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Global CA's have their root and intermediates recognised by all the modern browsers. However when browser encounter s a certificate whose intermediate and roots aka chain certificates & ca certificates are not a part of its trust store so it fails to chain the leaf certificate to its issuer. So in order to mitigate thi, the roots and intermediates of the company ca must be added so that the browser can verify the complete chain.

Comment: But you wouldn't want all the customers to install those root and intermediate certificates  via their browsers which is not actually right. To avoid this, i have the root and intermediate certificates also as a trust store in the keystore, but I see the certificate error on the browser that it is still not trusted. Is it something to do with .cer files that I used to import into keystore instead of .PEM files ?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed .but thats how the trust works. The company issues ca certificate is known only to your organization but browsers are accessed globally and if you want make the certificate trusted in all the browsers then either you switch to public ca issued certificates or get your root certificate cross signed by a global ca root.